# Why can't I override the padding from the user style agent on an input?

Tags: html, css

I want to make an input have a height that is the same as the font-size. As in, I want an input with a 16px font-size to have itself a height of 16px. Considering there is nothing that I can see that wouldn't make that possible I assume it is.

As you will see in the code below. I have tried basically everything I can to try and override this style. This includes inline and external styling with ! important on everything, more specific styles "padding-bottom" instead of "padding" for example, including CSS selectors that don't select my element but apply them. On top of that, it seems that 3px of the input's height comes from no style.

```css
input, input:matches([type="password"], [type="search"]) {
  border: none; 
  padding-top: none !important; 
  padding-bottom: none !important;
  padding-left: none !important; 
  padding-right: none !important; 
  margin: none !important; 
  outline: none; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  font-size: 16px; 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" oninput="myFunction()" style="border: none; padding-top: none !important; padding-bottom: none !important; padding-left: none !important; padding-right: none !important; margin: none !important; outline: none; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 16px; -webkit-appearance: none; font-weight: normal;">

</body>
</html>
```

Look here for the same code as above: https://codepen.io/AlexStiles/pen/vYBgpGX
[image]

Here is the problem according to the web inspector for Safari (the issue is present in Chrome and Firefox as well). It seems that the styles are invalidated. Note that the user agent is applying some padding and that the height is 20px and not 16px. Where that extra 3px comes from I have no idea.

Note: I don't want to set a height for the input, I want the height to be determined by the font-size.

Comment: additional comment on the answer below, you should have hovered on the `warning !` and it will say that property value not valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

err... You set a wrong value

> **All of true syntax**

```
/* <length> values */
padding-*: 0.5em;
padding-*: 0;
padding-*: 2cm;
/* <percentage> value */
padding-*: 10%;
/* Global values */
padding-*: inherit;
padding-*: initial;
padding-*: unset;
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-bottom

May be you need to set this right?

```
  padding-top: 0 !important; 
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
  padding-left: 0 !important; 
  padding-right: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
```

If you need trim off line height to same size with text-size

```
line-height: 16px;
```

**Warning**
[image]
that will make some character cut-out

Comment: Ok, that was a stupid mistake! Got rid of the padding but still got an extra 2px. Any ideas?

Comment: use `unset` or `0`

Comment: What do I apply those to?

Comment: ummm `<body>` has `~2px` **margin/padding** by defualt

Comment: That's not what I mean. I mean that despite fixing the padding issue, the height of the input element is still 2px more (18px) than the font size (16px). I can't see any style agent property that should cause this extra 2px. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `line-height: 16px;`

Comment: By default, some browser add 4px (2 top + 2 bottom) to input element's line-height. To avoid text cut-out

Comment: Still getting 18px in both safari and chrome.

Comment: so then cant it depend on web structure

Comment: So what, it can't be fixed?

Comment: yes I have tested is `line-height: 1.1;` so back to 1 px but cant anymore

Comment: or you set height is `16px`

Comment: if you want dynamic by fontsize may be you need scss or js